# a formula field displaying an image is not working in partner community sf1, but is fine on sf desktop

Tags: formula, images, community, partner

a formula field displaying an image works fine in internal org and partner community salesforce desktop, but it does not on sf1 in partner community

formula

```
IMAGE(Photo__c, "Photo Unvailable", 200, 200)
```

Photo__c is a URL field, that has a following value "c.na24.content.force.com/servlet/…; for one of the records

Comment: any help on above would be greatly appreciated, as i am stuck now with this

Comment: can you post the formula? Also the generated HTML in the partner community if possible

Comment: IMAGE(Photo__c, "Photo Unvailable", 200, 200)

Comment: Photo__c in above is a URL field, that has a following value "https://c.na24.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0151a0000001WEO" for one of the records

Comment: If i click the photo__c field in partner community, the image is displayed fine, w/ the following URL in browser address bar

Comment: https://<test-name>.force.com/partners/a051a000001XJn6

Comment: what happens when you try to visit that URL when logged into the SF1 partner portal (as a partner)?

Comment: the image is not displayed in SF1 for parter portal user

Comment: i tried to access the custom object that holds the photo__c and image formula field, and the images are not displayed via sf1 for partner portal user

Comment: Does the file download servlet work in S1 mobile?

Comment: no it is not working, and if i select the url, it does not do anything

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working in my org when using ImageServer instead of FileDownload. I also have the instance stuff stripped out from the start using a relative URL (may not be necessary).

As an example, I tested a URL field with this value:

```
/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015F0000003oBk4&oid=00DF00000006hty
```

And a Formula field with this value:

```
IMAGE(Photo_URL__c, "Test", 300, 100)
```

This is working in my community in Salesforce1 as well as the standard desktop environments. Don't forget to include both image ID and org ID when using ImageServer!

Comment: That worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the formula I used in my formula field. Make sure you store the images in Document and make it externally available. And it is working fine.

```java
HYPERLINK("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" 
& Mobile__c 
&" &text=%22Hello!%20" 
& Name&"%22",
IMAGE('https://auromirafilms--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0152w000000d3ga&oid=00D2w000008ojm1', "none" , 40, 45), "_self")
& ""
& HYPERLINK("tel:" & Mobile__c &"", IMAGE('https://auromirafilms--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0152w000000d3gf&oid=00D2w000008ojm1', "Red ",25,35)," _self")
&" "
& HYPERLINK("sms:" & Mobile__c &"", IMAGE('https://auromirafilms--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0152w000000d3gk&oid=00D2w000008ojm1', "Red ",24,33)," _self")
```